# Cannot resolve symbol 'servlet' error after new servlet creation in IntelliJ 2020 1.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, servlets

I am following a tutorial [Java EE Webapplication with servlet and jsp page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjkoQ5Cu8HM&list=PLTX5B0J16aFA1UUE3MZKS3Tl124eeMa_L)

It is of an older Intellij version. Mine is Ultimate 2020 1.1 and has another way of servlet creation that confuse me. In the tutoriol a user gets this:

[image]

I get something with `javax`, without a long import list and with the error
[image]

How can I get the simple way that is shown in the tutorial? Is the 2020 1.1 IntelliJ version better? Why has it the error?

**edit**
What I am doing exactly is this: after creating a simple jps file called login.jps, I press an item in a IntelliJ menu to create a servlet:
[image]

Then I fill out a form in this way and press OK:
[image]

Then the login.java file with the login class is created automatically. But the file differs from the tutorial one, because is related to the `javax` symbol.

Comment: Without having us look in a 40+ minutes video, you are getting that doing what, exactly?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Right. I have added an explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Can you also please post the error message? Because I only see the red line, but not the error itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have "red" unresolved code b/c there is no such library added to project. You need to add [servlet-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api) dependency to module, see Add a library to module dependencies﻿
 steps:

Global and project libraries are not available until you add them to module dependencies:

1. From the main menu, select **File | Project Structure** ⌘; and select **Modules**.
2. Open the **Dependencies** tab and click Add.
3. Select a library you want to add and click **Add Selected** at the bottom of the dialog.